# How to update my video read model in CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have an app that is using CQRS and in this app there are aggregates such as user video tag that are persisted and send events over to the query side to persist the read model.

I want to know how many views and shared the video has. So every time users watch o share the video I want to increase these counts. How can update only the video read model? because in my video write model I don't have number of views and shared. Should I create a command to send an event and update the read model or update the read model directly?

Answer (score 1):

The bounded context of view-and-sharing analytics is most likely orthogonal to the video bounded context. So these events are handled and stored by some other analytics engine.

Read model itself should not store any state that cannot be reconstructed from a source of truth. I.e. you should be able to drop and recreate a read model from scratch (I am not talking about computational resources that it could require). But a read model can (and often is) cross-domain. I.e. it queries multiple bounded contexts for the data. In your case it may query video and video analytics.

Comment: Let me get this straight, I have to create a bounded context called video analytics and store that events to be reconstructed and send them to create the read model. For example, when user watch a video send a command: addVideoViewsCountCommand this command has to store the event and send it to create/update the read model later. Is it correct?

Comment: Analytics is a little bit different. A view is not a command, it is a pure fact that you cannot reject. You don't have to make up a decision here - just register the fact of view. Hence there is no command - just an update (or rather create). Usually when there are a lot of things to track an RDBMS can become a bottleneck. Depending on whether you can tolerate some loss you may consider using Prometheus or Cassandra for it. And then update the read model with some batch job at a regular interval. But as a concept, just use RDBMS. Don't push each event to read model, let it pull batches instead